# SOQL on feedpollvote object

Tags: soql, polling

Is it possible to write SOQL to display the Last Name and Choice of a user who participated in a Chatter poll. I have the following SOQL so far.  I want the actual choice not the choice id.

```
SELECT id, LastName FROM User
             where id in (select CREATEDBYID from feedpollvote)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
SELECT CreatedBy.LastName, Choice.ChoiceBody from FeedPollVote
```

This yields one row per poll vote, including the last name of the user and the full text of the choice selected.

The relationships for this object are documented under [`FeedPollVote`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedpollvote.htm) (I like to look at the SOAP API reference as it often includes more detail than the object reference). `ChoiceId` is a reference to `FeedPollChoice`, so relationships are accessed through `Choice.`, and the relevant field names for that object are on [`FeedPollChoice`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedpollchoice.htm) (also part of the SOAP API reference).

Comment: Can you tell me how you knew that CreatedBy.LastName and Choice.ChoiceBody were options to use in the query?  I am not seeing that in the documentation that I see online.  I feel like I am missing an important resource.  Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, I should have included that in the first place. Thanks for asking; see the links I've added.